safeParse method does not return success at any point of time due to req.body being undefined?
router.post("/task", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    //@ts-ignore
    const userId = req.userId
    // validate the inputs from the user;
    const body = req.body;

    
    const parseData = createTaskInput.safeParse(body);

    console.log("Request Body:", body);
    console.log("Parse Data Result:", parseData);
    console.log("Content-type:", req.headers['content-type']);

    if (!parseData.success) {
        return res.status(411).json({
            message: "You've sent the wrong inputs",
            error: parseData.error.errors
        })
    }

    // parse the signature to ensure the user has paid

    let response = await prismaClient.$transaction(async tx => {

        const response = await tx.task.create({
            data: {
                title: parseData.data.title ?? DEFAULT_TITLE,
                amount: "1",
                //TODO: Signature should be unique in the table else people can reuse a signature
                signature: parseData.data.signature,
                user_id: userId
            }
        });

        await tx.option.createMany({
            data: parseData.data.options.map(x => ({
                image_url: x.imageUrl,
                task_id: response.id
            }))
        })

        return response;

    })

    res.json({
        id: response.id
    })

The code only runs the if-block and never goes to the next line.
When I try to send a POST request through Postman, then it gives me this
{
    "message": "You've sent the wrong inputs",
    "error": [
        {
            "code": "invalid_type",
            "expected": "object",
            "received": "undefined",
            "path": [],
            "message": "Required"
        }
    ]
}

However, I have input the correct createTaskInput and the program should return a json just with id as I send each POST request.

Can you share the POST request you're running through postman? body and headers

@JesusDiazRivero Headers have the key: Authorization and Content-Type with their associated values and the body is ```{
"options": [{
"imageUrl": "asd",
"imageUrl": "random_image_url"
}],
"signature": "0x123123123"
}````

I can't see any issue in this code, please edit your post and add createTaskInput Zod object and your POST request header, so we can clearly see what is going on.

Please add your request's POST headers and params from the DevTools; it will help in identifying the problem more effectively.
